# Two list create a new list include specific letters

Tags: prolog

I need to create two lists both list should have the same size.If the first list has example chockolate and the other has chockolan.Then it should be chockol in a list M.What i did is:

```
%same_letters([Head| Tail], [Head| Tail2]) :-
 % same_letters(Head),
 %   same_letters(Tail, Tail2).

same_letters([Head| Tail], List) :-
    \+ same_letters(Head),
    same_letters(Tail, List).
m(c,h,o,c,k,o,l).
m(h,e,l,lo).

% length
length([],0).
length([H|T],L) :-
    length(T,L1),
    L is L1+1. 


?- same_letters([c,h,o,c,k,o,l,a,n], List).
List = [c,h,o,c,k,o,l] ;
?-same_letters([h,a,e,l,o).
List = [h,l,o]

%check if is in list
List=[c,h,o,c,k,o,l,a,n,h,a,e,l,o].              
List = [c,h,o,c,k,o,l,a,n,h,a,e,l,o]  
     member(c,h,o,c,k,o,l,a,n,h,a,e,l,o, List).           
List = [c,h,o,c,k,o,l,a,n,h,a,e,l,o|_]?
```

Comment: `M(c,h,o,c,k,o,l).` and `M(h,e,l,lo).` are invalid Prolog syntax. A functor cannot begin with a capital letter. It's not clear what the intent of those two terms is in the context. Why are you defining `length/2`? It's already available in Prolog.

Comment: if it was small m?

Comment: With small `m` it's not any clearer. It would just no longer be a syntax error.